# asp.net mvc3 create a controller method that will be always executed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, action

I have a base controller from which every other controller inherits. I would like to create a method in there that will be executed in each view. Right now I have void method in Base controller that I just call in every action in every controller.

Is that even possible to do?

Thank you,

H

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with an `ActionFilterAttribute` and in MVC3 you can register the attributes globally or per controller.  You do not need to use a base controller.

You can define your attribute:

```
public class GlobalViewDataAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute { ... }
```

And then add it globally in your Global.asax.cs:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new GlobalViewDataAttribute());
```

To use it on every action in a controller use:

```
[GlobalViewData]
public class MyController : Controller {}
```